# nth child не работает

Tags: html, css

Первый элемент списка нужно сделать перечеркнутым текстом, ничего не получается.
Помогите пожалуйста.

```css
/*Обнуление*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :focus,
:active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active {
  outline: none;
}

nav,
footer,
header,
aside {
  display: block;
}

input,
button,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}


/*--------------------*/

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.list li {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background: url('../img/icons/li.svg') left 5px no-repeat;
  right: 10px;
}

.list li:nth-child(1) {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link"></a>
<div class="block">
  <div class="content-top">
    <ul class=list>
      <li>Put on this page information about your product</li>
      <li>A detailed description of your product</li>
      <li>Tell us about the advantages and merits</li>
      <li>Associate the page with the payment system</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Правильно будет `:first-child`. Дефис пропустили.

Comment: @UModeL, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy: вопрос на закрытие - опечатка.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<s>По идее можно просто воспользоваться тегом [`<s></s>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/s), который и перечеркнёт весь вставленный текст средствами HTML:</s> (упс, недоглядел изначальные требования, но этот способ тоже имеет право на жизнь)

UPD: если решать через nth-child, то Вы просто забыли поставить между `first` и `child` значит дефиса:

```css
.list li:first child { /* надо было написать first-child
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```css
/*Обнуление*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :focus,
:active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active {
  outline: none;
}

nav,
footer,
header,
aside {
  display: block;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

input,
button,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}


/*--------------------*/

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.list li {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background: url('../img/icons/li.svg') left 5px no-repeat;
  right: 10px;
}

.list li:first-child {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <title>CSS. Чикибряк</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="link"></a>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="content-top">
      <ul class=list>
        <li>Put on this page information about your product</li>
        <li>A detailed description of your product</li>
        <li>Tell us about the advantages and merits</li>
        <li>Associate the page with the payment system</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Неправильно скопировал код, пересоздаю вопрос

Comment: @Alex а зачем пересоздавать вопрос, если Вы можете с помощью кнопки "Править" внести все необходимые изменения без создания отдельного вопроса?

Comment: Исправил, сейчас правильно

Comment: @Alex обычно код подвергается правке в том случае, если нужно его дополнить/убрать ненужную информацию/добавить новую версию неработающего кода. Если же изменить код на полностью валидный, то это будет как-то не очень правильно. (К тому же последняя версия Вашего кода теперь выводит перечёркнутую первую строку текста, тем самым решая вопрос, поставленный Вами ранее)

Comment: Можете подсказать, если мне второй элемент нужно сделать перечеркнутым через nth-child, что нужно указывать?

Comment: @Alex достаточно написать `nth-child(-n+2)` — это верная форма записи nth-child, она возьмёт все целые n, при которых результат будет натуральным числом (http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child)

Comment: Благодарю, аллах акбар.

Comment: ни nth-child(-n+2) ни nth-child(2) не работают в моем случае, только first child.

Comment: @Alex возможно, у Вас не стоит CSS3 — метод nth-child работает только при нём, в отличие от first-child